# Is there a tangible award for the Most Active Contributors in SE?

Tags: discussion

Since I was elected as a SharePoint Stack Exchange (SE) moderator I am struggling to do what I promised in my [electoral program](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/1416#1416) that focuses on

- How do I appreciate all types of valuable SE members' contributions?
- How do I encourage the SE members to continue their great work?

So I have already prepared a monthly and quarterly annual report for the most active contributors at SharePoint Stack Exchange (SPSE) as a type of appreciation and encouragement which has attracted the admiration of many SPSE members.

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. Most Edited Questions Award.
15. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

You can check a sample of this report at [Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - July 2017](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-july-2017).

---

Now I would like to know

> Is it allowed to me as a SharePoint moderator to prepare a tangible award like
>   a **Certificate of Excellence** for the Top Contributors list as a type of appreciation to their great effort?

I have designed a humble sample, but I don't know: Do I have the permission as a moderator to share it with SE members or not?

[image]

---

**Please if it's allowed,** Anyone working at SE confirm me that.

By the way, it's not new badges or new function that requires additional programming, we just need a permission to grant this award to our top contributors as a type of appreciation for their great work!

- As a **Moderator** I consider that as a type of encouragement for the active contributors, I think it would increase the activity on SPSE,
- As a **Winner** I consider that as an honor to grant a documented award from a great community like Stack Exchange.

**Please if it's not allowed,** Could you please

- Suggest the Means (besides auto-badges and reputation) that can be used to increase contributors enthusiasm and encourage them to continue.
- Share with us the allowed tangible award for the Most Active Contributors.

Comment: How about you just get a PDF of it and you can make it tangible on your own?

Comment: That is a really poor font if the x is a decorated r. Also, you should probably talk to the people on Graphic Design. I'm pretty sure they'd tell you that five + fonts is too many.

Comment: thank you guys i have changed the font :)

Comment: Thank you @Catija as I mentioned I am not designer, I just show an idea if it accepted I will hire designer to do it, it just a sample, thanks again for your feedback :)

Comment: See my feature request for user nominated badges: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257361/user-nominated-badges

Comment: This is a super cool idea. I think that our community would be more dynamically and contributors would be more motivated, and they also will help much more each other. thumb up for your idea really like it :)

Comment: Better change "his" to "their" wherever you got it, there are also females around who won't like being referred to as males.

Comment: Thank you @Hamlet appreciate, really I **didn't ask about adding new badges**,  I just need to have a permission to share and grant a simple award like the above certificate for the active contributors as a type of appreciation for their great effort and encourage them to continue.I need to know Is it allowed to me as a moderator to do that or not?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank again for your valuable hint, I will :)

Comment: Please stop the useless edits just to bump. It is irritating. Very much, and abusing of your power. Use the edit feature to actually **edit**.

Comment: @animuson It was an 'x'. Some Fraktur fonts have _very_ similar glyphs for the lower case 'r' and lower case 'x', see e.g. [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur_(Schrift)#Schreib-_und_Lesehilfe) and [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Mostra_BreitKopf_Fraktur.png), where the two differ only by a thin line (curved or straight) at the bottom left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean this to be just something that users can put in their profile, or use as avatar, I really can't see any problem with that.

If you mean give those users something "real" like a badge, then it's not technically possible, and I doubt SE will add such a feature.

All in all, kudos for the efforts, and you better ask questions related to the design of this "certificate" on the per-site meta, not here. (Since it's not really related to SE in general. You might get helpful comments, but many users around here will not like this and might even close the question as specific to one site.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable reply, our main aim is what you have mentioned in the first point "this to be just something that users can put in their profile or use as avatar," as a **Moderator** I consider that as a type of appreciation for the active contributors, I think it would increase the activity on SPSE, as a **Winner** I consider that as an honor to grant a documented award from a great community like SE , regarding why I post it here it should be in SharePoint Meta? , I totally agree with you, but I  need first to know **Is it allowed or not?** Please help me to know that :)

Comment: Well, I'm not working for SE and can't speak on their behalf, but in my own opinion it's fine and allowed. IMO best wait a day or two, and if you don't get an official "no" here, go on with your idea.

Comment: Also, you did well to ask here, I was referring to your request for feedback on the design as being off topic.

Answer (score 5):

First off, nice work with the monthly contributors reports! The format is good but I love the breadth of coverage; it's good to see folks being recognized for the wide variety of contributions that are possible on these sites. There's a lot to be done on a site to take care of it, and this goes lengths in hitting what directions it can.

I don't see any issue with you providing an award such as what you've designed, provided it doesn't misrepresent the site or those who use it; that is, if you and the rest of the mod team are in agreement on presenting these awards then it's completely factual to state that "the moderator team recognizes X for doing Y" when X did in fact do Y and the mod team recognizes it.

As a precautionary matter, I will reach out to our lawyer just to make sure everything's fine in terms of trademark stoofs.

Also, we'd like to offer some additional support - something like printing and mailing physical copies of these awards on a yearly basis or so maybe? Kinda like how we currently award the users who reach high reputation levels, y'know. But I can't promise anything there; we've got a lot on our plates right now, and the cost and logistics of such a project are something that we'd need to plan ahead for. It'll be something we're pretty interested in looking at as we go into this next year, though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to contact SE directly, see the Trademark.

https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

> Do not use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Based on the attached link using the logo in my context is a **fair use** because I am not using it "in trade."

Comment: I reckon just give them t-shirts, I wear mine with pride. Reading your reply I wasn't sure if you were being sarcastic, I had to support SPS2003 for Microsoft, feel your pain.

Comment: Absolutely no, I am not sarcastic, I fully appreciated your valuable answer :) Thanks again for your precious time to reply to me!